# Update based on csv data

Tags: dml, visualforce, upload, update, dmlexception

I have a requirement to update records of custom object Incident_abv__c if the value of it's Name field in present in csv. I have below class and page to do the same. But when I click the Read csv button here it simply refreshes the page removing the csv I have chosen. Can someone please let me know where do I fail here? Debug log is showing no errors here.

Apex class:

```
Public with sharing class csvFileReaderController {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
Public string csvAsString{get;set;}
Public String[] csvfilelines{get;set;}
Public String[] inputvalues{get;set;}
Public List<string> fieldList{get;set;}
Public List<Incident_abv__c> sObjectList{get;set;}
  public csvFileReaderController(){
    csvfilelines = new String[]{};
    fieldList = New List<string>();
    sObjectList = New List<sObject>();
  }

  Public void readcsvFile(){
       csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
       csvfilelines = csvAsString.split('\n');
       inputvalues = new String[]{};
       for(string st:csvfilelines[0].split(','))
           fieldList.add(st);  

       for(Integer i=1;i<csvfilelines.size();i++){
           Incident_abv__c inc= new Incident_abv__c() ;
           string[] csvRecordData = csvfilelines[i].split(',');

           if(inc.name == csvRecordData[0])            
           {inc.status_abv__c = 'Open';
           inc.Report_Publish_Date_abv__c = Date.today();
            if(inc.Rep_abv__c !=null)
                inc.OwnerId = inc.Rep_abv__c; 
           }                                                                             
           sObjectList.add(inc);  
       }
  }
}
```

Apex page:

```
<apex:page controller="csvFileReaderController">
<apex:form >  <!-- csv reader demo -->
    <apex:pageBlock id="theid">
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" >
              <apex:inputFile value="{!csvFileBody}"  filename="{!csvAsString}"/>

              <apex:commandButton value="Read csv" action="{!readcsvFile}"/>

        </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageblocktable value="{!sObjectList}" var="rec">
          <apex:column value="{!rec.name}" />
          <apex:column value="{!rec.Rep_abv__c}" />
          <apex:column value="{!rec.OwnerId}" />
          <apex:column value="{!rec.Incident_Loaded_Date_abv__c}" />
          <apex:column value="{!rec.Report_Publish_Date_abv__c}" />
          <apex:column value="{!rec.No_Of_Transactions_abv__c}" />
          <apex:column value="{!rec.Status_abv__c}" />
    </apex:pageblocktable>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: check this out https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_a_CSV_with_APEX

Comment: Can you please let me know what change do I need here? Is this an issue with splitting comma from the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd resolve this by adding a rerender to the commandbutton, but unfortunately that's not allowed in combination with apex:inputfile.

So alternatively, you could not initialize the sObjectList in the `csvFileReaderController` but initialize it in the getter method (after checking whether it has already been initialized or not).

So replace the declaration of sObjecList by the following:

```
Public List<Incident_abv__c> sObjectList{
    get{
        if(sObjectList == null) sObjectList = new List<Incident_abv__v>();
        return sObjectList;
    }
    set;
}
```

And remove the sObjectList initialization from the `csvFileReaderController()` method.

Comment: Thanks but now it is showing this error:   Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.

Comment: ah yes you're right.. Forgot about that (ran into it lots of times myself...) I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have placed actionregion that overcomes above error and now gives this error:                   System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.
Error is in expression '{!readcsvFile}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page csvfilereadercontroller: Class.csvFileReaderController.readcsvFile: line 15, column 1   i.e.        at this line ::   csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();

Comment: now the csvFileBody is not being returned properly to the controller. Try my alternative.

Comment: Thanks but since it's a non-void method , getting this.  Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement

Comment: So sorry. see updated answer including a return statement now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20030/discussion-between-sfdc-geek-and-guy).

Comment: Hi
Thanks a ton!!
But now it errors out here
System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null. 
Error is in expression '{!readcsvFile}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page csvfilereadercontroller: Class.csvFileReaderController.readcsvFile: line 21, column 1
i.e. csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
this line

Comment: did you remove the actionregion tags?

Comment: No I didnt. I can't understand why that error comes back again. Is the csvfilebody still null ?

Comment: **sorry to continue here but I can't get the chat working** Actually you should have removed the actionregion tags. Because if you have those tags, only the part between the tags will be submitted to the controller. If you remove the tags, the whole page will be submitted (including the csvfilebody)

Comment: But I haven't altered anything.

Comment: The VF code that's currently in your question will not work. It should not contain the actionRegion tags. Also it still contains the 'rerender' in the commandButton, which will fail. That also needs to be removed.  (If this is not your current code, pls update it with your current code)